# Android SDK and windows 8

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I´ve instaled Windows 8 (clean install) and android SDK.
when I try to start any AVD I get this error:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'Android4'
Failed to create Context 0x3005
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
```

I´ve try all what I´ve found in stackoverflow:  GPU emulation=yes on AVD, copying libEGL_translator.dll,libGLES_CM_translator.dll, libGLES_V2_translator.dll, libOpenglRender.dll from android-sdk\tolos\lib to android-sdk\tolos and problem goes on.

if I run "emulator" or "emulator-arm" from command line I get the same error.

before this I´ve Windows 7 on the same computer and work ok.
Android SDK works 20.0.3  on Windows 8? what could be the problem?

Comment: It is not clear to me: the emulator does not work at all or it does with some errors logged?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try some new UNIX (clean install) :) Ok what have you see in your error log?
I think its win 8 driver problem, driver for using OpenGL

> Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software tenderer.

Try whit new drivers for windows 8 :D or try to find solution for win 8 OpenglES problem in google

Comment: And pls accept answers if they work, you have 0% accepting rate, so i will not post for you anymore. Sry

Comment: Should be a comment on the question, not your answer :D

Comment: Ah forget the reputation restriction. Nevertheless it isn't my question :)

Comment: Thanks I´m traying to find new video card driver